# SQL dividing a count from one table by a number from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with taking a Count() from one table and dividing it by a correlating number from a different table in Microsoft SQL Server.

Here is a fictional example of what I'm trying to do

Lets say I have a table of orders. One column in there is states.

I have a second table that has a column for states, and  second column for each states population.

I'd like to find the order per population for each sate, but I have struggled to get my query right.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Orders.State, Count(*)/
(SELECT StatePopulations.Population FROM Orders INNER JOIN StatePopulations
on Orders.State = StatePopulations.State 
WHERE Orders.state = StatePopulations.State )
FROM Orders INNER JOIN StatePopulations
ON Orders.state = StatePopulations.State
GROUP BY Orders.state
```

So far I'm contending with an error that says my sub query is returning multiple results for each state, but I'm newer to SQL and don't know how to overcome it.

Comment: Don't paraphrase the error. Post it - all of it - exactly as reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a correlated sub-query, then this should do it...

(You don't need to join both table in either the inner or outer query, the correlation in the inner query's where clause does the 'join'.)

```
SELECT
  Orders.state,
  COUNT(*) / (SELECT population FROM StatePopulation WHERE state = Orders.state)
FROM
  Orders
GROUP BY
  Orders.state
```

Personally, I'd just join them and use MAX()...

```
SELECT
  Orders.state,
  COUNT(*) / MAX(StatePopulation.population)
FROM
  Orders
INNER JOIN
  StatePopulation
    StatePopulation.state = Orders.state
GROUP BY
  Orders.state
```

Or aggregate your orders before you join...

```
SELECT
  Orders.state,
  Orders.order_count / StatePopulation.population
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Orders.state,
    COUNT(*) AS order_count
  FROM
    Orders
  GROUP BY
    Orders.state
)
  Orders
INNER JOIN
  StatePopulation
    StatePopulation.state = Orders.state
```

(Please forgive typos and smelling pistakes, I'm doing this on a phone.)